# Application crashes without giving any message

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to open videos in webview. When I  try to load webview then application crashes without giving any message. It is happening when I installed adobe flash player10.1 in my emulator to play videos.

```
public class VideoWeb extends Activity
{

WebView mWebView;
String video="<table bgcolor=\"#666666\"><tr><td><iframe width=\"300\" height=\"260\" frameborder=\"0\" id=\"player\" type=\"text/html\"src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/iiLepwjBhZE?enablejsapi=1&origin=example.com\"></iframe></td></tr><tr><td><iframe width=\"300\" height=\"260\" frameborder=\"0\" id=\"player\" type=\"text/html\"src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/lBMMTeuJ_UQ?enablejsapi=1&origin=example.com\"></iframe></td></tr><tr><td><iframe width=\"300\" height=\"260\" frameborder=\"0\" id=\"player\" type=\"text/html\"src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/BZMkY3y7nM0?enablejsapi=1&origin=example.com\"></iframe></td></tr><tr><td><iframe width=\"300\" height=\"260\" frameborder=\"0\" id=\"player\" type=\"text/html\"src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/BZMkY3y7nM0?enablejsapi=1&origin=example.com\"></iframe></td></tr><tr><td><iframe width=\"300\" height=\"260\" frameborder=\"0\" id=\"player\" type=\"text/html\"src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/oAUNloEf1ME?enablejsapi=1&origin=example.com\"></iframe></td></tr></table>";
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web_view);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,video,"text/html", "utf-8",null);
}
```

}

```
Logcat shows:11-04 13:09:31.342: WARN/webview(285): Miss a drag as we are waiting   
 for    WebCore's response for touch down.11-04 13:09:31.842: INFO/DEBUG(31): *** ***  
 *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***    *** *** ***
 11-04 13:09:31.842: INFO/DEBUG(31): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic
 /:2.2/FRF91  /43546:eng/test-keys'
11-04 13:09:31.842: INFO/DEBUG(31): pid: 285, tid: 293  >>> com.example.vidushi <<<
11-04 13:09:31.842: INFO/DEBUG(31): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr fe03953b
11-04 13:09:31.842: INFO/DEBUG(31):  r0 817be6e0  r1 810e5378  r2 810e5373  r3 006f6cfc
11-04 13:09:31.842: INFO/DEBUG(31):  r4 817be6e4  r5 0000000b  r6 00000004  r7 00000000
11-04 13:09:31.842: INFO/DEBUG(31):  r8 46a52d88  r9 41855f1c  10 41855f04  fp 00230a50
11-04 13:09:31.842: INFO/DEBUG(31):  ip 810000dc  sp 46a52650  lr 810e5379  pc  
b0001330  cpsr 80000010
11-04 13:09:32.132: INFO/DEBUG(31):          #00  pc b0001330  /system/bin/linker
11-04 13:09:32.152: INFO/DEBUG(31):          #01  pc 000e5376  /data/data  
/com.adobe.flashplayer/lib/libflashplayer.so
11-04 13:09:32.152: INFO/DEBUG(31):          #02  pc 000e5376  /data/data 
/com.adobe.flashplayer/lib/libflashplayer.so
11-04 13:09:32.152: INFO/DEBUG(31):          #03  pc 000e5376  /data/data  
/com.adobe.flashplayer/lib/libflashplayer.so
11-04 13:09:32.152: INFO/DEBUG(31):          #04  pc 000e5376  /data/data   
/com.adobe.flashplayer/lib/libflashplayer.so
11-04 13:09:32.152: INFO/DEBUG(31):          #05  pc 000e5376  /data/data 
/com.adobe.flashplayer/lib/libflashplayer.so
11-04 13:09:32.152: INFO/DEBUG(31):          #06  pc 000e5376  /data/data 
/com.adobe.flashplayer/lib/libflashplayer.so
11-04 13:09:32.152: INFO/DEBUG(31):          #07  pc 000e5376  /data/data 
/com.adobe.flashplayer/lib/libflashplayer.so
11-04 13:09:32.182: INFO/DEBUG(31):          #08  pc 000e5376  /data/data 
/com.adobe.flashplayer/lib/libflashplayer.so
11-04 13:09:32.182: INFO/DEBUG(31):          #09  pc 000e5376  /data/data
/com.adobe.flashplayer/lib/libflashplayer.so
11-04 13:09:32.252: INFO/DEBUG(31):          #31  pc 000e5376  /data/data
/com.adobe.flashplayer/lib/libflashplayer.so
11-04 13:09:32.252: INFO/DEBUG(31): code around pc:
11-04 13:09:32.252: INFO/DEBUG(31): b0001310 2b60688b 4a23d112 4e214b24 18e218a0 
11-04 13:09:32.252: INFO/DEBUG(31): b0001320 4c2319a5 33201c2b 68099400 21c09101 
11-04 13:09:32.252: INFO/DEBUG(31): b0001330 97020089 f0012500 e02afe5f 0072268c 
11-04 13:09:32.252: INFO/DEBUG(31): b0001340 1c0d435a 18ae350c 3301604e 608b36a4 
11-04 13:09:32.252: INFO/DEBUG(31): b0001350 4d126030 0052228c 68451960 36a41c2e 
11-04 13:09:32.252: INFO/DEBUG(31): code around lr:
11-04 13:09:32.252: INFO/DEBUG(31): 810e5358 f85ee00c 68513003 47986892 bd00b003 
11-04 13:09:32.252: INFO/DEBUG(31): 810e5368 eb006810 e7f60061 bf004b56 f8dfa100 
11-04 13:09:32.252: INFO/DEBUG(31): 810e5378 b09cc158 a91c185b f8534a54 f8df000c 
11-04 13:09:32.252: INFO/DEBUG(31): 810e5388 189ac150 0d70f841 e882c903 a91c0003 
11-04 13:09:32.252: INFO/DEBUG(31): 810e5398 000cf853 0c10f102 0d68f841 e88cc903 
11-04 13:09:32.252: INFO/DEBUG(31):     46a52610  81002180  /data/data/com  
.adobe.flashplayer/lib/libflashplayer.so
 11-04 13:09:32.252: INFO/DEBUG(31):     46a52620  817be000  /data/data
/com.adobe.flashplayer/lib/libflashplayer.so
11-04 13:09:32.282: INFO/DEBUG(31):     46a5269c  817dbfb8  /data/data
/com.adobe.flashplayer/lib/libflashplayer.so
11-04 13:09:32.282: INFO/DEBUG(31):     46a526ac  00506c2d  [heap]
11-04 13:09:32.282: INFO/DEBUG(31):     46a526b4  b0002b11  /system/bin/linker
11-04 13:09:36.172: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(59): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.984MB for   
65553-byte allocation
```

Comment: If possible can you test this on a device of different make?

Comment: it works just fine on my device (ver 2.3.3).